# Different between setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds and setCompoundDrawables in Android TextView

Tags: android

I have read document about two this method here[TextView Android Refernce](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

i can see the different between them is:

> The Drawables' bounds will be set to their intrinsic bounds.

But what is intrinsic bounds ? As my understand, intrinsic bounds is the size of the drawable, right?

Comment: Yes it is the size the drawable itself would like to have. For example, a BitmapDrawable will have intrinsic bounds for the size of the Bitmap, but for a ColorDrawable there are no reasonable intrinsic bounds.